# git pull origin master keeping the settings.py

Tags: git, github

I'm new on programming and I'm developing a Django Web app. I'm using git too, but everytime I do `sudo git pull origin master` I have to edit the settings.py to change the production file settings. What's the best way to keep this file intact?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would want to add your `path/to/settings.py` to the `.gitignore` file in the root folder of your git repository. This will allow git to stop tracking the particular file. Your purpose is a typical use case of what needs to go into `.gitignore`.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).